# Borrowing money without clear plan of how to pay it back

Tags: halacha, money, borrowing

Are you allowed to borrow money from a Jew without having a reasonable idea how you will be able to repay the loan?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I hope you register as a user so that you can get more benefit from this site.  I edited your post a bit -- I deleted the second sentence which was difficult to understand and seemed to not add anything.  Please revise if it had more meaning.

Comment: אמר להם, צאו וראו איזוהי דרך ישרה שידבק בה האדם רבי אליעזר אומר, עין טובה רבי יהושע אומר, חבר טוב רבי יוסי אומר, שכן טוברבי שמעון אומר," הרואה את הנולד" רבי אלעזר אומר, לב טוב אמר להם, רואה אני את דברי אלעזר בן ערך מדבריכם, שבכלל דבריו דבריכם אמר להם צאו וראו איזוהי דרך רעה שיתרחק ממנה האדם רבי אליעזר אומר, עין רעה רבי יהושע אומר, חבר רע רבי יוסי אומר, שכן רע רבי שמעון אומר," הלוה ואינו משלם" I believe this is how some peirushuim explain this Mishna in Avos 2:9 one who doesn't see in the future to pay back his loan he owes.

Answer (score 3):

[This site](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1664261/jewish/Loan-to-Someone-Who-Cannot-Repay.htm#footnote3a1664261) says

> Just like there is strong language when it comes to giving loans,
>   Jewish law also uses strong words for those who take loans without the
>   means or the intention to repay them.

and quotes [Rambam Hilchos Malveh veLoveh 1:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1159438/jewish/Malveh-veLoveh-Chapter-1.htm) writes (with my emphasis):

> Similarly, it is forbidden for a borrower to take a loan and use it when
>   it is unnecessary and lose it, **leaving his creditor without a source
>   to collect the debt.** This applies even if the owner is very wealthy.
>   A person who acts in this way is wicked, as [Psalms
>   37:21](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16258/jewish/Chapter-37.htm#v=21)
>   states: "**A wicked man borrows and does not pay**." Our Sages
>   commanded: "Treat money belonging to your colleague as dearly as your
>   own."

from which it is clear that you are not allowed to borrow money from someone without clearly knowing how it will be paid back.

**Edit: There has been some discussion about the Rambam's meaning.**

I now add quotes from

[Rabbi Aron Tendler on Hilchos Choshen Mishpot](http://torah.org/advanced/business-halacha/5757/vol1no10.html) who writes

> The lender has a right to demand proper collateral for his loan to
>   guarantee that it will be paid back in a timely manner. **If the
>   lender is not satisfied with the guarantees provided, he has no
>   obligation to lend, even if the borrower is a poor person.** It is
>   essential that a person keep in mind when faced with this situation
>   that all of his actions must be L'Shem Shomayim (For The Sake Of
>   Heaven).

[Rabbi Yitzchok A. Breitowitz](http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/bank.html#Foot2) who writes

> At the same time, however, the debtor's obligation to pay is
>   considered to be an **absolute obligation** and there is no mechanism
>   in halakhah that is tantamount to escaping your debts by filing a
>   bankruptcy and obtaining a discharge.

[Meir Tamari](http://www.torah.org/learning/business-ethics/)  in his book [“With all your possessions”](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765760592) who writes:

> On the other hand the debtor too has religious obligations. He is not
>   permitted wilfully to mismanage the funds given him, nor may he spend
>   them on riotous living. **Above all the debtor is obligated to return
>   the loan at the date agreed upon; any deviation to this is akin to
>   theft.** The unconditional obligation to repay loans is an important
>   concept that has applications not only in the sphere of credit, but
>   also for many aspects of the modern economy.

These quotes **do not explicitly prohibit** you from borrowing money from a Jew without having a reasonable idea how you will be able to repay the loan.

Bearing in mind the **absolute obligation** and that deviation from repayment on time **is akin to theft** it would certainly be **wise** to take a loan only when you know clearly how it will be paid back.

“Wise” but not “required”. And the lender need only loan when he is satisfied with the guarantees provided.

In a less nuanced way, [my first source](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1664261/jewish/Loan-to-Someone-Who-Cannot-Repay.htm#footnote3a1664261) does say however

> Just like there is strong language when it comes to giving loans,
>   Jewish law also uses strong words for those who take loans **without
>   the means or the intention to repay them.**

Comment: Then what is someone who is destitute supposed to do, beg instead? Then of what purpose is the admonition against refusing a loan? You're only required to give loans to wealthy people?

Comment: Not having a clear plan is different from not intending to return it

Comment: When does a lender take a loan anyway?

Comment: @SethJ On your second comment, Rambam says וכן אסור ללוה ליקח הלואה so as you point out the translation is a problem and I have edited it.

Comment: @SethJ On your first comment - someone who knows he cannot repay a loan should rather accept tzedoko. (That's what he is doing effectively if he takes a loan and does not repay it. The one who gives tzedoko may "dress it up" as a loan to spare the feelings of the poor man.) I believe you are only required to give **loans** to those who can repay who may not necessarily be wealthy but who are certainly not destitute.

Comment: @SethJ, a common structure of a loan to a poor person would be to purchase merchandise to sell at a markup. At no time (other than an Ones) is he without the means to repay. Another is where liquidity is his problem - he has possessions that may even be used as a security for the loan, but lacks money to transact business and earn a living, and wants to avoid irrevocably selling the possessions.

Comment: @yishai, that's not what this answer proposes or implies.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok You are required to give loans to those who are destitute. See *M'chilta* (*Sh'mos* 20:22): רבי ישמעאל אומר, כל אם שבתורה רשות חוץ משלשה... כיוצא בו, אם כסף תלוה את עמי את העני עמך וגו' חובה. אתה אומר חובה, או אינו אלא רשות תלמוד לומר העבט תעביטנו, חובה ולא רשות. This is echoed by the Rambam ([*Hil. Malveh v'Loveh* 1:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=13&hilchos=76)). See also CM 97.

Comment: @Fred Where do you see the need to loan to the destitute who cannot repay? I quoted the Rambam too 1:3. He can't mean both things.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok The Rambam (1:3) says that "it is forbidden for a borrower to take a loan for no reason and then just waste it the principle so that he will have no means of repayment." You can't assume that, just because a person is destitute, he wants a loan just to fritter it away on nonsense. It's more than likely that he wants to use the loan to help get himself out of poverty. If a poor person was automatically considered a deadbeat, the Rambam never would have written (1:1): "The Torah was strict on someone who refrains from lending to the destitute."

Comment: @Fred Your comments are persuasive. But please see my extensive edit of my original answer.